# Perl: edit file, not just output to shell

Tags: perl

I found a little one-liner of perl code that will change the serial in my zone-files on my Bind server.
However it wont change the actual file, it just gives me the output directly to the shell.

This is what I run:

```
find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 perl -e "while(<>){ s/\d+(\s*;\s*[sS]erial)/2015050466\1/; print; }"
```

This gives me the correct output to the shell and if I remove the `print;` at the end of the perl line nothing happens and I want it to actually change the files to the output I got.

I'm a total noob when it comes to Perl so this might be a simple fix so any answer would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am assuming you want to replace the string inside the files found by `find`.
Command example below will change **in-place** (`-i`) any `"foo"` with `"bar"` for all `*.txt` files from curent directory.

```
find . -type f -name '*.txt' -print0 | xargs -0 perl -p -i -e 's/foo/bar/g;'
```

And for your question, you should be able to get it with this command:

```
find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 perl -p -i -e 's/\d+(\s*;\s*[sS]erial)/2015050466\1/;'
```

Note: It is good habit to always use single quotes rather than double quotes. This is because inside double quotes, a `\`, `$`, etc. may be processed by the shell before passed to Perl. See [Bash manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Double-Quotes.html).